# Launch Firefox from IE

Tags: firefox, activex, activexobject

Is there any effective way to open Firefox (e.g. click on a link) from IE?

The only method I found is using ActiveX, but it will show a security warning unless we change security settings in IE options.

Here is my current method:

```
var cmd = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');
cmd.Run('firefox.exe ' + url);
```